# How to perform an action after performSegue is finished in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Is there any possible way to perform an action after a segue has finished in swift?

I am calling this code:

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDamageReportSegue", sender: self)
```

The segue opens a new ViewController modal and after the user presses the done button I want it to continue running the code underneath which is

```
self.performReservationEndingSequence() // which does some calls etc
```

Is there maybe a `completion handler` for `performSegue` that I am missing? I've been searching but I cannot find this specific question.

Comment: You mean to perform something when you dismiss view controller?

Comment: cant you do it in your next view controller's `viewDidLoad` ? or in `viewWillDisappear`

Comment: You can write code in viewwilldisappear call

Comment: This segue is called multiple times but only on this instance it should perform the `self.performReservationEndingSequence()` so `viewWillDissapear` is not an option.

Comment: @FinleySiebert there is a `prepareForSegue` method which is called before performSegue, you can call your function there. and also check if segue.identifier == "yourIdentifier" , then only call the function, else dont

Comment: See if you can use this (perform handler) : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistoryboardsegue/1621910-seguewithidentifier?language=objc

Answer (score 4):

A reasonable solution is a callback closure.

- In the *showDamageReportSegue* controller add a callback property

  ```
  var callback : (() -> Void)?
  ```
- In the *showDamageReportSegue* controller call `callback` in `viewDidDisappear`

  ```
  override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated : Bool) {
      super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
      callback?()
  }
  ```

  or at any other arbitrary place.
- In the first view controller implement `prepare(for` and set the callback

  ```
  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
     guard segue.identifier == "showDamageReportSegue" else { return }
     let destination = segue.destination as! ShowDamageReportController // change that to the real class
     destination.callback = {
         self.performReservationEndingSequence() 
     }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Write it in `viewDidDisappear` event of the view controller.

```
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    print("ViewController Dismissed")
}
```

Edit: For some code to execute over a specific segue, use prepare delegate method with the triggering segue's identifier and it should execute whenever that segue is triggered:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier  == "SomeViewController" {
      print("Segue triggered for SomeViewController")
    }
}
```

Comment: But the function should be called on specific occasions and viewDidDisapear will always run

Comment: @FinleySiebert check the answer now

Answer (score 0):

You can try swift's method :

```
viewDidDisappear()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a prepareForSegue method which is called before `performSegue`, you can call your function there. and also check if `segue.identifier == "yourIdentifier"` , then only call the function, else dont

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "yourSegueIdentifier" {
        self.performReservationEndingSequence() // call the function
    } else {
        print("dont call the function")
    }
}
```